# How to display emojis into php which are comes from ios encoding?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, emoji

we are developing the  ios application and one step we are getting stuck.

in the application screen emojis are save thorugh the api in php using ios functions NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding so in php there would like

```
Sportlich drauf \ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffc, bin ein gro\337er Barca fan \ud83d\udc99\u2764\ud83d\udc9b. Besch\344ftige mich viel mit Kunst, Architektur und Geschichtlicher Kunst in meinem schul Verlauf 
\ud83d\ude04. H\366r sehr gerne deutsch Rapp \ud83c\udfbc\ud83c\udfbb, lese gerne Mangans und bin absoluter anime fan \ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffc. Rauche und trinke kaum, ich paffe gerne eine Zigarre in sch\366nen Moment und trink nur auf events \ud83d\ude09.
```

so how this converted emojis are decoded in webpage and shows as actual emojis

we are using php as server side and mysql as database.
can any php library or anyother things would help then let me know.

i just want to decode that string in php and show emojis in webpage.

Comment: in your website you have to display emoji like facebook chat ?

Comment: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php refer this link for convert unicode to emoji in php side

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya :  Hello himanshu i want to just display emoji nothing else i want to disply in admin panel

Comment: Ya say brother what you want

Comment: like anywhere display this string but with emoji not like character \ud83d\

Comment: First you clear that you have problem to display emoji in your website ? or your application in device ?

Comment: display emoji in website

Comment: i just post one answer try that demo . implement that in your site hope your problem solve.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myInput = '\\ud83d\\ude01';

$myHexString = str_replace('\\u', '', $myInput);
$myBinString = hex2bin($myHexString);

print iconv("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", $myBinString);
```

**Happy Coding**

Comment: if this not working @Darshanambaliya then try this ...

$myInput = '\\ud83d\\ude01';

$myHexString = str_replace('\\u', '', $myInput);
$myBinString = hex2bin($myHexString);

print iconv("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", $myBinString);

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/

You just need to download Emoji.php and covert unicodes to emojis.

```
require_once('Emoji.php');

$text='Sportlich drauf \ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffc,Barca fan \ud83d\udc99\u2764\ud83d\udc9b \ud83d\ude09.';

echo Emoji::Decode($text);
```